# How to remove auto-generated YOSYS comments?

Tags: verilog, yosys

When I synthetize my verilog code using YOSYS the netlist generated contains comments like: (* src = "counter.v:6" *). I want to obtain a netlist file without these comments.

This is my `counter.v`

```
module counter (clk, rst, en, count);
    input clk, rst, en;
    output reg [1:0] count;

    always @(posedge clk)
        if (rst)
            count <= 2'd0;
        else if (en)
            count <= count + 2'd1;
endmodule
```

This is my YOSYS script `counter.ys`:

```sh
read_verilog counter.v
hierarchy -check -top counter
proc; opt; memory; opt; fsm; opt
techmap; opt
splitnets -ports;;
dfflibmap -liberty mycells.lib
abc -liberty mycells.lib
clean
write_verilog netlist.v
```

And this is the output file `netlist.v`

```
/* Generated by Yosys 0.8+576 (git sha1 dd8d264b, clang 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 -fPIC -Os) */

(* top =  1  *)
(* src = "counter.v:1" *)
module counter(clk, rst, en, \count[0] , \count[1] );
  (* src = "counter.v:6" *)
  wire _00_;
  (* src = "counter.v:6" *)
  wire _01_;
  wire _02_;
  wire _03_;
  wire _04_;
  wire _05_;
  wire _06_;
  wire _07_;
  wire _08_;
  wire _09_;
  wire _10_;
  (* src = "counter.v:3" *)
  input clk;
  (* src = "counter.v:4" *)
  output \count[0] ;
  (* src = "counter.v:4" *)
  output \count[1] ;
  (* src = "counter.v:3" *)
  input en;
  (* src = "counter.v:3" *)
  input rst;
  NAND _11_ (
    .A(_08_),
    .B(_10_),
    .Y(_06_)
  );
  NAND _12_ (
    .A(_09_),
    .B(_06_),
    .Y(_07_)
  );
  NOR _13_ (
    .A(_05_),
    .B(_07_),
    .Y(_01_)
  );
  NOT _14_ (
    .A(\count[1] ),
    .Y(_08_)
  );
  NOT _15_ (
    .A(rst),
    .Y(_09_)
  );
  NAND _16_ (
    .A(en),
    .B(\count[0] ),
    .Y(_10_)
  );
  NOR _17_ (
    .A(en),
    .B(\count[0] ),
    .Y(_02_)
  );
  NOR _18_ (
    .A(rst),
    .B(_02_),
    .Y(_03_)
  );
  NAND _19_ (
    .A(_10_),
    .B(_03_),
    .Y(_04_)
  );
  NOT _20_ (
    .A(_04_),
    .Y(_00_)
  );
  NOR _21_ (
    .A(_08_),
    .B(_10_),
    .Y(_05_)
  );
  (* src = "counter.v:6" *)
  DFF _22_ (
    .C(clk),
    .D(_00_),
    .Q(\count[0] )
  );
  (* src = "counter.v:6" *)
  DFF _23_ (
    .C(clk),
    .D(_01_),
    .Q(\count[1] )
  );
endmodule
```

Comment: you can filter them out by `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, or any other available utility, or write s script.

Comment: Try this command in gvim :g/\/\/.*/d

Comment: I know that something like this: 
```bash
sed -i '/\(\*.*\*\)/d' ./netlist.v
```
will do the work, but I want to know if there is any YOSYS command to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `write_verilog -noattr` - these are Verilog 2001 attributes not comments.